# Sending array of bytes to socket server

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x, sockets, websocket

I have two lamps, which I can switch on/off by socket. I have a socket server and have to create a client. The client has sent an array of 4 bytes. First byte - id of command (on/of), second id lamp, etc.
I have code in C#:

```
void BtnCmd22Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                if (clientSocket.Connected) 
                {
                    Byte[] mes = new Byte[4];   

                    mes[0] = 0x22;
                    mes[1] = (byte)cmbCmd22_0.SelectedIndex;
                    mes[2] = (byte)cmbCmd22_1.SelectedIndex;
                    mes[3] = (byte)nmCmd22_2.Value

                    serverStream.Write(mes, 0, 4);
                    serverStream.Flush();
}}
```

And I have to re-write it in Python. What I try:

```
HOST = 'some_host'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 9090       # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

b = bytearray(4)

b[0] = 0x22
b[1] = 1
b[2] = 1
b[3] = 0


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:

    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.send(b)
```

Also I try packers, but it isn't work. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Did you verify that this C# code is indeed sending the bytes 0x22, 1, 1, 0? It's not clear from this snippet of code what the values of the last three bytes are.

Comment: Also "socket" is a rather general term. Are these TCP sockets in both cases?

Comment: @Thomas, (byte) before values does not mean that it are bytes? Yeap, it is TCP sockets in both cases.